# Plotly create inset choropleth (Mapbox ideally) of Alaska and Hawaii

Tags: python, plotly, mapbox, plotly-python

Is there a way to create additional choropleth (ideally Mapbox choropleths, but I'd settle for Plotly's standard choropleth function) maps and layer them on top of a base choropleth so that I can easily show data related to Alaska and Hawaii with the continental US?

[Something like this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/apyh5.gif)

Don't believe my existing code is necessarily helpful, but here's how I build my base map (removed my custom style so that anyone should be able to generate).

```
fig = px.choropleth_mapbox(
    df_mar,
    geojson=puma,
    locations="stpuma",
    color="inter_pct",
    range_color=(0,25),
    color_continuous_scale="Viridis",
    labels={"inter_pct": "Marriage (%)"},
    center={"lat": 37.0902, "lon": -95.7129},
    zoom=4.2,
    opacity=1.0,
    mapbox_style="white-bg"
)
fig.update_layout(
    coloraxis_colorbar=dict(
        bgcolor="rgba(22,33,49,1)",
        title="Marriage,<br>Percent Share",
        titlefont=dict(
            color="rgba(255,255,255,1)"
        ),
        tickfont=dict(
            color="rgba(255,255,255,1)"
        ),
    ),
    margin=dict(
        l=50,
        r=50,
        b=50,
        t=50,
        pad=4
    ),
    paper_bgcolor = "rgba(8,18,23,1)",
    plot_bgcolor = "rgba(8,18,23,1)",
    showlegend = True,
    annotations = [
        dict(
            x=-0.025,
            y=-0.04,
            xref='paper',
            yref='paper',
            text='Source: Census ACS 5 2015-2019',
            showarrow = False,
            font=dict(
                color="rgba(255,255,255,1)"
            ),
            bgcolor="rgba(8,18,23,1)",
        )
    ]
)
fig.update_traces(
    marker_line_width=0,
    below="waterway"
)
fig.show(width=1920, height=1080)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- it can be achieved with **mapbox**
- key concept is modify geometry to meet you layout requirements.  Hence have done https://shapely.readthedocs.io/en/stable/manual.html#affine-transformations to move *Alaska* and *Hawaii*
- also found that *Alaska* geometry was give issues given it crosses date line.  Hence clipped geometry after transformation as well
- for good measure added **layers** to indicate geometry has been manipulated
- included maritime boundary to demonstrate how it can be extended to additional geometries

```
import geopandas as gpd
import shapely.geometry
import numpy as np
import plotly.express as px
import requests, io
from pathlib import Path
from zipfile import ZipFile
import urllib
import pandas as pd
from shapely.affinity import affine_transform as T

# US geometry
urls = [
    "https://www2.census.gov/geo/tiger/GENZ2018/shp/cb_2018_us_state_5m.zip",
    "https://maritimeboundaries.noaa.gov/downloads/USMaritimeLimitsAndBoundariesSHP.zip",
]
gdfs = {}
for url in urls:
    f = Path.cwd().joinpath(urllib.parse.urlparse(url).path.split("/")[-1])

    if not f.exists():
        r = requests.get(url, stream=True, headers={"User-Agent": "XY"})
        with open(f, "wb") as fd:
            for chunk in r.iter_content(chunk_size=128):
                fd.write(chunk)
        zfile = ZipFile(f)
        zfile.extractall(f.stem)

    gdfs[f.stem] = gpd.read_file(
        list(f.parent.joinpath(f.stem).glob("*.shp"))[0]
    )  # .to_crs("EPSG:4326")

gdf2 = gdfs["cb_2018_us_state_5m"]
gdf2 = gdf2.set_index("STUSPS", drop=False)
gdf2["color"] = gdf2["STATEFP"].astype(int)


# move alaska and hawaii using affine transform
t = {"AK": [0.6, 0, 0, 0.6, -20, -15], "HI": [3, 0, 0, 3, 385, -42]}
clip = (-179, 15, 0, 150)
gdf3 = gdf2.copy()
gdf3.loc[t.keys(), "geometry"] = gdf3.loc[t.keys(), ["geometry"]].apply(
    lambda g: shapely.ops.clip_by_rect(T(g["geometry"], t[g.name]), *clip), axis=1
)

gdf_m = gdfs["USMaritimeLimitsAndBoundariesSHP"]
gdf_m = gdf_m.dissolve("REGION")
tm = {"Alaska": "AK", "Hawaiian Islands": "HI"}
gdf_m.loc[tm.keys(), "geometry"] = gdf_m.loc[tm.keys(), ["geometry"]].apply(
    lambda g: shapely.ops.clip_by_rect(
        T(g["geometry"], t[tm[g.name]]), *gdf3.loc[tm[g.name]].geometry.bounds
    ),
    axis=1,
)


px.choropleth_mapbox(
    gdf3,
    geojson=gdf3.geometry.__geo_interface__,
    locations=gdf3.index,
    color="color",
    hover_name="NAME",
).update_layout(
    mapbox={
        "style": "carto-positron",
        "center": {"lon": -98, "lat": 33},
        "zoom": 2.5,
        "layers": [
            {
                "source": shapely.geometry.box(
                    *gdf3.loc[box].geometry.bounds
                ).__geo_interface__,
                "type": "fill",
                "color": "blue",
                "opacity": 0.1,
            }
            for box in t.keys()
        ]
        + [
            {
                "source": gdf_m.geometry.__geo_interface__,
                "type": "line",
                "color": "blue",
                "line": {"width": 1},
            }
        ],
    },
    margin={"l": 0, "r": 0, "t": 0, "b": 0},
)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for this!  I suppose the only downside is that this approach won't move the underlying Mapbox layer, right?  The issue I'm running into is that I'm projecting water tiles over my traces in order to get more granular detail in the coastline.  Any movement of the trace without moving the water layer will lose that detail.  Have you come across this issue before?

Comment: this approach will work for all geometry,  you need to move associated geometries in same way.  i.e. if Alaska has a defined water geometry move that to. as you see **color** works correctly with moved Alaska and Hawaii geometry

Comment: have extended with maritime geometries to demonstrate how this can work